# Using COUNTIF/SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, date, formulas, array-formulas

I have a worksheet that I am trying to make more automated by providing users with updates, however I am having difficulty with getting a formula to work.

I am using a semi-large table (over 32 columns of information, 1,500 rows) but really only want to focus in on 2 columns for this issue.  In column C I have the dates that a service order has been requested and in column D I have information that populates when a confirmation of the request is sent (if no request is sent, then it is blank). My hope is to be able to create a message box that alerts when the workbook opens and displays the number of order requests that are within 2 weeks of today that have not yet received a confirmation.

So far, it looks like my best option is to have hidden cells elsewhere that do the heavy lifting with formulas and then to display the values within a messagebox using a Workbook_Open event.  I have been able to get a formula to display the number of requests that fit my time window:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table5[Date]>=TODAY())*(Table5[Date]<=TODAY()=14))
```

And this appears to be capturing the numbers that I need, however I am having difficulty integrating the second component that I need: whether or not a reply was sent.  So far, my attempts at including some form of an AND qualifier within the formula has returned an error... I am hoping to be able to quantify within the formula something along the lines (logically) of this:

```
=IF(Table5[Reply]="" AND Table5[Date]>=TODAY()+14, SUMPRODUCT)
```

I know that the above won't work, but I am wondering if anyone has any pointers on how to modify this so that it can include both factors?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking at dates that are today and up to two weeks in the future, and that the Reply column is blank `""` for those dates, then these formula will work for you:

Excel 2007 or higher:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table5[Date],">="&TODAY(),Table5[Date],"<="&TODAY()+14,Table5[Reply],"")
```

Backwards compatible:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table5[Date]>=TODAY()),--(Table5[Date]<=TODAY()+14),--(Table5[Reply]=""))
```